# Access Azure storage account from Azure Function App

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-blob-storage, azure-storage-account

I am trying to deploy azure function to function App via Visual studio code. But facing access issue forbidden 403 to storage account. Azure storage account access level is private. Due to data security reason I don't want to change access level. Do we have any option to resolve this issue without changing access level in storage account?

Comment: is it no public endpoint or selected network ?

Answer (score 0):

- One of the workarounds is to whitelist the outbound IPs of the Function App in your storage account.
- Before doing this make sure the function and the storage account are in different regions because if they are in the same region the requests take place internally which wouldn't go through any outbound IP Addresses.
- If they are in different regions the storage account checks the IP addresses and allows the requests.
- Since the storage account doesn't allow public access it wouldn't have the IPs listed which are to be allowed and therefore you need to add the outbound IP Addressess in the storage account.

Comment: Can you help with any Microsoft documentation supporting your 2nd point?